# Angular 2: misunderstanding with imports

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanna port some of structure from angular 1.4...

And I have some troubles. For example I have such structure:

[image]

components - is a module, customer is a module, list - is a module.

I have troubles with importing modules & components.

I do it in a such way:

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ComponentsModule,
    CoreModule,
    ServicesModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<customer-list></customer-list>
```

and if I use here angular2 bootstrap:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
      demo
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

everything is ok.

**components.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomerModule } from './customer/customer.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [CustomerModule]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

**customer.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { ItemComponent } from './list/item/item.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerComponent, ListComponent, ItemComponent],
  exports: [CustomerComponent, ListComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

**list.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { ItemComponent } from './item/item.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListComponent, ItemComponent],
  exports: [ListComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

**list.component.html**

```
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <ngb-panel >
      <template ngbPanelContent>
        test
      </template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
```

And here I get error:

> zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'ngb-panel' is not a known element:

But if I import `NgbModule` in every module, till I reach app.module - everything is fine. But this is ridiculous.

Is there any possibility, to organize imports of modules in angular 2, so, that I don't need to import them in every module, once imported in root - I can reuse them in nested modules, like it was in angular 1.4 (using ngInject)?

Comment: If you only use the `NgbModule` inside your `ListModule` then you should only need to import it there. You got that right :) Maybe a long shot, but could the extra space in the `<ngb-panel >` be the problem?

Comment: @PierreDuc
seems that it doesn't help(

Answer (score 2):

To use `NgbModule` inside your `ListModule` you should add it to the imports array like you did. But you should also import it in your `AppModule`. So only in two places. The module where you use it, and the `forRoot()` import at the root module which also imports the `BrowserModule`:

*only relevant code: **AppModule***

```
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ]
...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*only relevant code: **ListModule**:*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations : [
    ListComponent,
    ItemComponent
  ],
  exports : [
    ListComponent,
    ItemComponent
  ]
})
export class ListModule{}
//you named this CustomerModule for some reason....
//could also be the problem, or just a wrong copy paste :)
```

If you then want to use the `ListComponent` inside your `CustomerModule`, you should import the `ListModule` and not the `ListComponent`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ListModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerComponent],
  exports: [CustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

If you only import the `ListComponent` it won't see the `NgbModule` you imported in your `ListModule`. Rule of thumb, only import/declare components which belong to that module. Don't import/declare components/directives/pipes/services from other modules. Only import the entire module. You can however export one module in the other. This way, if you import the module which exported another module, the other module is also available. (this doesn't make a lot of sense). Let me write it down for you:

*Components module only export customer module*

```
@NgModule({
   exports : [
      CustomerModule
   ]
})
export class ComponentsModule{}
```

*Customer module importing and export list module*

```
@NgModule({
   imports : [
     ListModule
   ],
   exports : [
     ListModule
   ]
})
export class CustomerModule{}
```

*List module exporting list component*

```
@NgModule({
   imports : [
     NgbModule
   ],
   declarations: [
     ListComponent
   ],
   exports : [
     ListComponent
   ]
})
export class ListModule{}
```

*App module importing the components module*

```
@NgModule({
   imports : [
     BrowserModule,
     NgbModule.forRoot()
     ComponentsModule
   ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

As far as i know, you will now be able to use the `ListComponent` inside your `AppModule`. Because the customer module also exports the `ListModule`. I think this is a bit counter-intuitive though, and would advice to only import the list module inside the customer module, and export the list module inside the components module.

Comment: Why do you declare ListComponent inside CustomerModule? If you want to use the ListComponent, you should import ListModule inside your CustomerModule. I believe this is where your problem is. I've updated my answer

Comment: good)
why i'm using nesting: for me in angular 1.4 it was much easier and obvious to have for example: components/cards/list/item, neither separate them on one level...

Comment: How would you organize such structure?
for example i have customer screen, with customers list or customer details (with some shared styles, like panel), list & customer have their own route path. Is my schema suitable for this, or not?

Comment: Customer would be a module which include the customer list and customer detauls. Your components module would export components to make a list and perhaps even a detail screen. Your customer module imports this components module to build the detail and list screen. Your appmodule imports the customer module. But this only applies if your componentsmodule is going to behave like a commons module, otherwise i see now use for the components module

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39160035/3375021) answer in another thread, so it seems like it's not possible in Angular 2, as every component are modular pieces and needs it's own imports, because otherwise the modularity would be lost.

You can have detailled instructions on how to use them [here as well.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#)

Comment: yes, ok
every module is importing dependencies.

but why if i use ngbModule in list module, i need to import it in customer, components etc?

Comment: You need to import it in every module you use, because there is not anything like a "parent" module or something, every module has his own dependencies and therefore needs its own imports.

Comment: check my question... so is it true, that i need to import ngbModule everywhere (components, customer) even if i didn't use it in app view? i use only list module in app view

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a module in Angular2 is that it's a standalone *reusable* module. This does however mean that whatever the module requires **must** be imported by the module itself.

If the imported modules are inherited, the modules are no longer standalone and thus no longer reusable and you lose most of the benefits of a modular system.

Comment: yes, ok every module is importing dependencies. but why if i use ngbModule in list module, i need to import it in customer, components etc?

Comment: You should only need to import it into any module that declares Components, Pipes, Directives, etc that use something from the imported module.

Comment: check my question... so is it true, that i need to import ngbModule everywhere (components, customer) even if i didn't use it in app view? i use only list module in app view

Comment: You only import it in the actual module that defines the Component that uses it. In your example you use it in the `list.component.html`. It's not clear what Component that template belongs to, nor what Module that component is defined in. But assuming that this template is used by a ListComponent that is defined in the ListModule, then you'd only need to add the ngbModule to the imports of the ListModule