# Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "mdlButton"

Tags: angular, typescript, pug, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I'm building an application using [angular2-mdl](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl). Everything works just fine except that all animations won't work.

After looking the documentation available at the following [link](http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/), I noticed that, for instance, if I want to toggle a specific menu after a click on a button I have to use a syntax like the following:

```
<button mdl-button #btn1="mdlButton" (click)="m1.toggle($event, btn1)" mdl-button-type="icon" mdl-ripple><mdl-icon>more_vert</mdl-icon></button>
<mdl-menu #m1="mdlMenu" mdl-menu-position="bottom-left">
   <mdl-menu-item mdl-ripple (click)="action()">Some Action</mdl-menu-item>
   <mdl-menu-item mdl-ripple mdl-menu-item-full-bleed-divider>Another Action</mdl-menu-item>
   <mdl-menu-item mdl-ripple disabled>Disabled Action</mdl-menu-item>
   <mdl-menu-item>Yet Another Action</mdl-menu-item>
</mdl-menu>
```

Menu's documentation is available [here](http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/menu).

Unfortunately, when I try to replicate the same behavior with the following code:

```
button(mdl-button, mdl-button-type='icon', '#morebtn'="mdlButton" '(click)'="moremenu.toggle($event, morebtn)")
    mdl-icon more_vert
mdl-menu(mdl-menu-position='bottom-right', '#moremenu'="mdlMenu")
    mdl-menu-item About
    mdl-menu-item Contact
    mdl-menu-item Legal Information
```

That gets compiled to:

```
<button mdl-button="mdl-button" mdl-button-type="icon" #morebtn="mdlButton" (click)="moremenu.toggle($event, morebtn)">
    <mdl-icon>more_vert</mdl-icon>
</button>
<mdl-menu mdl-menu-position="bottom-right" #moremenu="mdlMenu">
    <mdl-menu-item>About</mdl-menu-item>
    <mdl-menu-item>Contact</mdl-menu-item>
    <mdl-menu-item>Legal Information</mdl-menu-item>
</mdl-menu>
```

I get the error I mentioned in the title. A full error trace is available at the following [pasted.co log](http://pasted.co/4ce535a7).

I experienced a similar issue in past with `ngForm` using `#f="ngForm"` and I solved by importing `import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';` on the component that threw that error.

So I've been scratching my head for a while trying to import `mdlButton` and `mdlMenu` like

```
import { MdlButtonComponent } from '@angular-mdl/core/components/button/mdl-button.component';
import { MdlMenuComponent } from '@angular-mdl/core/components/menu/mdl-menu.component';
```

But the error persists.

I have two modules:

- `app.module.ts` : where I import `MdlModule` to make it available to the whole application
- `pages.module.ts` : where I import all the components needed in pages

**Why am I getting this even though I'm following the documentation? How can I fix this?**

Comment: I guess above code is in a different module than where you added `MdlModule` to `imports: [...]`. You need to add the module to imports in any module where you are using MDL directives.

Comment: I'm importing `MdlModule` on `app.module.ts`, thus is available to that component. Honestly I have no idea of where and what I should import such directives.

Comment: Do you have other `@NgModule()`s?

Comment: Yes, I have a `pages.module.ts` where I import all the components I need. I tried to import `MdlModule` there and now everything works. Thanks for the hint, I also got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159792/angular2-app-module-with-root-level-imports/39186107#39186107). I edited my question to highlight that. If you want to post the answer you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives, components, and pipes from one module, used in another module must be added to imports (`@NgModule({ imports: [MdlModule], ...})`) of every module where they are used.
Adding it to imports of `AppModule` doesn't make them globally available.

So, you'll have to remove `MdlModule` import from `app.module.ts` and import it into `pages.module.ts`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186107/4684539)'s a related answer as you mentioned and [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1473)'s a related issue on [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2).